# Axes recovery after plotting in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

After plotting the output of multiple methods from text files, the right and upper sides of the axes are not shown. I need to have them and bold them alike the current axes.

The data plotted comes from files in which data for each method have been stored. Each data file is a 256x2 file that includes values between [0,1]. The first column is the precision and the second column is the recall.

```
figure
hold on
for m = 1:length(methods)
  prFileName = strcat(readpath,dataset, '_', methods{m}, '_PRCurve.txt');
  R = load(prFileName);
  precision = R(:, 1);
  recall = R(:, 2);
  plot(recall, precision,'color',methods_colors(m,:),'linewidth',2);    
end
axis([0 1 0 1]);
hold off
grid on;
legend('methode one','method two')
xlabel('Recall','fontsize',12);
ylabel('Precision','fontsize',12);
set(gcf,'color','w');  %Background color
ax = gca;  % current axes
ax.GridLineStyle='-';
ax.GridAlpha=0.7;
ax.XAxis.LineWidth=4;
ax.YAxis.LineWidth=4;
Grid.LineWidth = 3;
set(gca,'FontName','Arial','FontWeight','bold');
```

**My output:**

[image: plotted figure]

**Original data:**

```
[0.201612 1.000000;0.473895 0.813213;0.509366 0.775938;0.524163 0.756849;0.536319 0.744732;0.544424 0.734892;0.552313 0.727097;0.557654 0.719293;0.561069 0.713474;0.565138 0.708002;0.568720 0.705004;0.572685 0.702411;0.574115 0.698205;0.576529 0.697134;0.579346 0.694858;0.581070 0.693213;0.582026 0.692059;0.584509 0.691119;0.585875 0.690336;0.586489 0.688838;0.588433 0.688227;0.589985 0.687624;0.590905 0.687562;0.591892 0.687045;0.592426 0.686695;0.592972 0.686332;0.593253 0.685255;0.594198 0.684903;0.594672 0.684895;0.595856 0.684581;0.597124 0.684201;0.597278 0.683989;0.597886 0.683861;0.598499 0.683794;0.598724 0.683701;0.599475 0.683571;0.599827 0.683561;0.600251 0.683438;0.600228 0.683277;0.600305 0.683071;0.600476 0.683067;0.600579 0.683004;0.600339 0.682803;0.600213 0.682141;0.600268 0.682016;0.600542 0.681904;0.600381 0.681840;0.600448 0.681840;0.600538 0.681726;0.600627 0.681659;0.600770 0.681635;0.600905 0.681482;0.600917 0.681375;0.600734 0.681307;0.600734 0.681307;0.600642 0.681264;0.600720 0.681253;0.601444 0.681184;0.601480 0.681184;0.601718 0.680955;0.601821 0.680955;0.601821 0.680955;0.601958 0.680955;0.602177 0.680655;0.602539 0.680655;0.602674 0.680606;0.602864 0.680606;0.602911 0.680606;0.603022 0.680606;0.603022 0.680606;0.603273 0.680606;0.603358 0.680579;0.603520 0.680579;0.603818 0.680579;0.604029 0.680565;0.604191 0.680565;0.604191 0.680565;0.604371 0.680494;0.604637 0.680476;0.605386 0.680460;0.606010 0.680460;0.606078 0.680460;0.606290 0.679936;0.606984 0.679548;0.607291 0.679497;0.607659 0.679472;0.607994 0.679306;0.608470 0.679037;0.608442 0.678970;0.608796 0.678807;0.609303 0.678714;0.609547 0.678657;0.609927 0.678467;0.610346 0.678302;0.610899 0.677652;0.611175 0.677652;0.611448 0.677301;0.612511 0.677155;0.612640 0.676402;0.613280 0.676402;0.613623 0.676277;0.614415 0.675417;0.615243 0.674605;0.615911 0.674601;0.617164 0.674601;0.618662 0.674476;0.619177 0.674388;0.619723 0.673993;0.620740 0.673695;0.621668 0.673350;0.622682 0.673323;0.623195 0.673204;0.624675 0.673204;0.625555 0.672728;0.626095 0.672155;0.627775 0.672047;0.628613 0.671499;0.629023 0.670547;0.631015 0.670339;0.631373 0.670017;0.632461 0.668883;0.632942 0.668662;0.634569 0.668323;0.635285 0.668082;0.637139 0.667239;0.637270 0.666458;0.638917 0.666368;0.639765 0.666115;0.640943 0.665808;0.641661 0.665704;0.643633 0.665529;0.646006 0.665529;0.646658 0.665329;0.647392 0.664908;0.648859 0.664090;0.649985 0.663583;0.651193 0.662677;0.653684 0.660258;0.654840 0.660054;0.656786 0.659874;0.657570 0.659235;0.658537 0.659190;0.660890 0.658122;0.662920 0.657568;0.664260 0.656880;0.666298 0.656280;0.666916 0.655978;0.668178 0.655131;0.668919 0.654870;0.670389 0.654441;0.670619 0.653603;0.671624 0.652875;0.673049 0.652183;0.674315 0.651285;0.676130 0.651027;0.677092 0.649799;0.678081 0.649090;0.679300 0.648262;0.680943 0.647865;0.680100 0.646171;0.681178 0.645171;0.683523 0.644520;0.683755 0.643928;0.686075 0.643146;0.686905 0.642111;0.688256 0.641657;0.689233 0.641242;0.690506 0.640521;0.692826 0.638231;0.695227 0.637420;0.696323 0.636512;0.697808 0.635450;0.699692 0.633850;0.700870 0.631655;0.701216 0.629642;0.702549 0.628882;0.704164 0.627596;0.705130 0.626842;0.705018 0.624658;0.705942 0.623999;0.707372 0.622667;0.710428 0.621794;0.711609 0.620519;0.713404 0.619295;0.714931 0.617914;0.718499 0.617104;0.720724 0.615774;0.721662 0.614693;0.723181 0.612491;0.723878 0.611185;0.725945 0.609251;0.730281 0.607118;0.730874 0.603678;0.731970 0.600906;0.731515 0.599001;0.732504 0.595722;0.733421 0.592995;0.737195 0.590840;0.738140 0.588574;0.741949 0.587039;0.742875 0.582400;0.743972 0.580038;0.746218 0.579074;0.746583 0.575588;0.749146 0.573102;0.751960 0.570159;0.754440 0.568951;0.754986 0.565920;0.754947 0.561872;0.756065 0.559606;0.758321 0.557936;0.760394 0.555468;0.762893 0.552402;0.764336 0.550675;0.764178 0.547292;0.764643 0.542969;0.767369 0.538886;0.770228 0.536357;0.770978 0.531705;0.770111 0.525041;0.773011 0.521905;0.772255 0.515662;0.775366 0.512602;0.777668 0.509482;0.778520 0.503849;0.779642 0.498346;0.781965 0.492270;0.784695 0.488000;0.785982 0.479703;0.796597 0.473706;0.798725 0.468719;0.800086 0.461603;0.800464 0.455319;0.798910 0.446695;0.800251 0.439831;0.799404 0.431637;0.799290 0.423563;0.800032 0.417575;0.799825 0.408827;0.801278 0.398664;0.802286 0.389090;0.802335 0.381111;0.803801 0.370771;0.812162 0.360939;0.812584 0.347896;0.816370 0.337255;0.817368 0.324137;0.818456 0.308642;0.814710 0.292338;0.819548 0.278081;0.818203 0.262530;0.822571 0.246382;0.828031 0.223384;0.831524 0.190471;0.819948 0.162071;0.811546 0.118579]
```

Comment: The upper and right axis do not so much as disappear, as they do "not exist". With making them all bold, do you mean to plot a thick line around your figure as a frame? You could plot a vertical and horizontal thick black line at the desired position

Comment: Please add some sample data as well so that the plot is reproducible.

Comment: @Adriaan , When in bar() function, I bold on axis, its own parallel axis also bolds. My plan was to do so with this plot. Is there any efficient way for doing that? If not, how your proposed suggestion can be implemented?

Comment: @kkuilla , The question is updated.

Comment: That's not sample data. Add some actual data we can use to make a plot; `rand(256,2)` would probably already suffice, given the problem is just about the axes.

Comment: Can't you just use `set(gca,'LineWidth',4)` ?

Comment: @Adriaan ,   rand(256,2) may be good but in few minutes I try to add the original data.

Comment: @obchardon , Unfortunately, that doesn't work.

Comment: It is remarkable that the attached data, stored in a ".txt" file and MATLAB readSsfrom that file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`box on` will turn on the display of the box around the graph area. I believe this is what you are asking for.

You might need to use `set(ax,'LineWidth',4)` rather than `ax.XAxis.LineWidth=4` and `ax.YAxis.LineWidth=4`, I'm not sure of the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the working solution. "set(ax,'LineWidth',4)"  also bolds the grid.