# Defining specific color and line type for each curve in a loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matlab-figure

By plotting the curves in a loop that each curve is related to its own stored data (i.e. method) in [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59308649/axes-recovery-after-plotting-in-matlab), how is it possible to change and define a new specific color and line type (e.g. "--") for each method's curve after the loop?

```
figure
hold on
for m = 1:length(methods)
  prFileName = strcat(readpath,dataset, '_', methods{m}, '_PRCurve.txt');
  R = load(prFileName);
  precision = R(:, 1);
  recall = R(:, 2);
  plot(recall, precision,'color',methods_colors(m,:),'linewidth',2);    
end
axis([0 1 0 1]);
hold off
grid on;
box on;
legend('methode one','method two')
xlabel('Recall','fontsize',12);
ylabel('Precision','fontsize',12);
set(gcf,'color','w');  %Background color
ax = gca;  % current axes
ax.GridLineStyle='-';
ax.GridAlpha=0.7;
ax.XAxis.LineWidth=4;
ax.YAxis.LineWidth=4;
Grid.LineWidth = 3;
set(gca,'FontName','Arial','FontWeight','bold');
```

> For convenience in implementation, each method's data can be assumes as `rand(256x2)`.

Comment: you can go through all the 'children' of your axes object to find the plot objects, and set their 'color' from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lines_obj = findobj(h, 'Type', 'Line')`, and `set(lines_obj, ...`.

Example:

```
h = figure;

%Plot something
x = -6:0.1:6;
plot(x, sin(x), x, cos(x), x, sin(x.^2), x, cos(x.^2));

%Find all lines in figure
lines_obj = findobj(h, 'Type', 'Line');

%Set style of all lines to '--'
set(lines_obj, 'LineStyle', '--');
```

result:
[image]

---

In case you need to set different style for each line, and you need to match as specific type to specific plot...

Keep an array of line objects while plotting, and use a for loop:

```
close all

g = gobjects(4); %Initialize and array with 4 graphics objects.

x = -6:0.1:6;
g(1) = plot(x, sin(x), 'r');hold on %Keep returned object in g(1)
g(2) = plot(x, cos(x), 'g'); %Keep returned object in g(2)
g(3) = plot(x, sin(x.^2), 'b');
g(4) = plot(x, cos(x.^2), 'y');

%Cell array of styles.
styles = {'-', '--', ':', '-.'};

%Array of width values
widths = [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2];

%Modify the style of each line:
for i = 1:length(g)
    g(i).LineStyle = styles{i};
    g(i).LineWidth = widths(i);
end
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution. With which command the line width of each curve can be changed?